# Attaching several existing modified entitities to the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is the best way to do something like this:

```
var existingEntities = new [] 
{ 
      new Product {Name = "Name1", Count = 10}, 
      new Product {Name = "Name2", Count = 20}
}; 

using (var context = new ProductContext()) 
{ 
    // attach several entities

    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Should I iterate every entity and set it to State = EntityState.Modified?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iterating and setting

```
context.Entry(existingproduct).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

is the way to go.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx